# After migrating a project from Vue to Nuxt, I get dependency errors. How do I fix them?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to migrate a project from Vue2 to Nuxt3, mostly because of SEO problems, and when I try to nom run dev it, I get these errors :

```
These dependencies were not found:
child_process in ../node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js 
fs in ../node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js
```

This is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "v-owl-carousel": "^1.0.8",
    "vmodal": "^0.1.13",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@iconify/vue2": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

I'm working with legacy code I haven't built from scratch and don't know where child_process or fs are used, how can I find them and stop this problem from happening ?

It's also weird to me that none of my modules appear in the package.0json

Comment: What is weird ? You have some package inside node-module that you use in your project but is not appear inside the package.json ?

Comment: You do have Nuxt2 in your `package.json`, consider starting by using the v3. Also, if you're just starting I could recommend starting [from scratch](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation) because quite some of your packages will require a migration here. (I do not recommend using jQuery via Owl-carousel too...) Also, why do you want to migrate to Nuxt3 here? What are the issues? It would probably be faster to fix those in Nuxt2 than doing a migration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the dependency it's asking for?

```
npm i xmlhttprequest
```

Comment: This is not a dependency per-se: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: It is a dependency in NodeJS. He's using Nuxt, so there will be SSR in the project.

Comment: Depends, and you don't need to install it if it's already baked-in in Nuxt. I never had to install that, and who would in 2022 anyway?

Comment: The w3 standard XHR is baked into serverside Nuxt? Also he's working on a legacy codebase which used this 7-year old node package. Look at the logs, it's importing from node_modules.

Comment: Oh, nvm it's a browser API and it's indeed not included into Node. Still it's a package with no updates for 3 years while unjs team have h3 and ohmyfetch. Clearly not something needed here. The project is probably not legacy, there should be something else in the given file.

Comment: Nuxt 2.15.8 is a relative "legacy" and OP has found the issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem, it came from me using Parse. Requiring parse instead node/parse fixed it for now but I suspect there will be other problems relating to that later down the lane.

Comment: Can you give us more details please?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).